# Float not equal after division followed by multiplication

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm testing a small and simple library I made in Ruby. The goal is to convert from `EUR` to `CNY` and vice versa. Simple.

I tested it to be sure everything works but I got an unexpected issue. When I use `to_euro` followed by `to_yuan` it should go back to the original `amount` ; it doesn't happen. I tried to `.to_f` or `round(2)` the `amount` variable which fix some tests, raise new ones, but it's never equal to what I expect globally ; I'm running out of idea to fix this :(

```
class Currency

  attr_reader :amount, :currency

  def initialize(amount, currency='EUR')
    @amount = amount
    @currency = currency
  end

  def to_yuan
    update_currency!('CNY', amount * Settings.instance.exchange_rate_to_yuan)
  end

  def to_euro
    update_currency!('EUR', amount / Settings.instance.exchange_rate_to_yuan)
  end

  def display
    "%.2f #{current_symbol}" % amount
  end

  private

  def current_symbol
    if currency == 'EUR'
      symbol = Settings.instance.supplier_currency.symbol
    elsif currency == 'CNY'
      symbol = Settings.instance.platform_currency.symbol
    end
  end

  def update_currency!(new_currency, new_amount)
    unless new_currency == currency
      @currency = new_currency
      @amount = new_amount
    end
    self
  end

end
```

**Tests**

```
describe Currency do

  let(:rate) { Settings.instance.exchange_rate_to_yuan.to_f }

  context "#to_yuan" do

    it "should return Currency object" do
      expect(Currency.new(20).to_yuan).to be_a(Currency)
    end

    it "should convert to yuan" do
      expect(Currency.new(20).to_yuan.amount).to eql(20.00 * rate)
    end

    it "should convert to euro and back to yuan" do
      # state data test
      currency = Currency.new(150, 'CNY')
      expect(currency.to_euro).to be_a(Currency)
      expect(currency.to_yuan).to be_a(Currency)
      expect(currency.amount).to eql(150.00)
    end

  end

  context "#to_euro" do

    it "should convert to euro" do
      expect(Currency.new(150, 'CNY').to_euro.amount).to eql(150 / rate)
    end

  end

  context "#display" do

    it "should display euros" do
      expect(Currency.new(10, 'EUR').display).to eql("10.00 €")
    end

    it "should display yuan" do
      expect(Currency.new(60.50, 'CNY').display).to eql("60.50 ¥")
    end

  end


end
```

**And here's my RSpec result**

[image]

**I'm pretty sure this problem is very common, any idea how to solve it easily ?**

Comment: Don't use Float, but BigDecimal, if you need precise results.

Comment: use multiplication instead of division.

Comment: `Float` is imprecise almost always [Nice Article on how this is true in most programming languages](http://itreallymatters.net/post/386327451/floating-point-arithmetics-in-19-programming#.V59qqaK1VwA). For precise math use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float isn't an exact number representation, as stated in the [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html):

> Float objects represent inexact real numbers using the native architecture's double-precision floating point representation.

This not ruby fault, as floats can only be represented by a fixed number of bytes and therefor cannot store decimal numbers correctly.

Alternatively, you can use ruby [Rational](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Rational.html) or [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html)

Its is also fairly common to use the [money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) when dealing with currency and money conversion.