# ruby exact number log (logarithm) function

Tags: ruby, logarithm

As the base 10 logarithm of 1000 is 3 you might expect `Math::log(1000, 10)` to return `3`. Instead it returns `2.9999999999999996`.

This is due to the fact floats in Ruby are not exact numbers as discussed for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38702825/2799887):

> Float isn't an exact number representation, as stated in the [ruby
>   docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html):
>
> > Float objects represent inexact real numbers using the native architecture's double-precision floating point representation.
>
> This not ruby fault, as floats can only be represented by a fixed
>   number of bytes and therefor cannot store decimal numbers correctly.
>
> Alternatively, you can use ruby [Rational](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Rational.html) or [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html)

Sadly when calling `Math::log(BigDecimal('1000'), BigDecimal('10'))` the result is exactly the same. Same goes for `Math::log(Rational('1000'), Rational('10'))`. There is also a `BigMath::log` which [does something completely different](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigMath.html#method-c-log).

Now the big question is: how can we calculate the base 10 logarithm of 1000 such that we get the exact result: `3`?

Comment: When searching the web on "ruby bigdecimal log" there is not a lot I could find that is relevant, at least not at the moment of this writing. So I hope this question on stackoverflow fills that gap. Even more so when it is accompanied by an actual answer :-)

Comment: Hmm, surprisingly Math::log10(1000) returns 3.0

Comment: You can have a look at the source & docs here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Math.html#method-c-log10. I am still trying to understand the implementation

Answer (score 4):

You have encountered a limitation of floating point numbers here. [`Float`s typically have a precision of 15 decimal places in Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Float.html), but the value `2.9999999999999996` shows 16 decimal places of (unreliable) precision.

To get back to a reliable precision, round to 15 decimal places:

```
>> Math::log(1000, 10)
=> 2.9999999999999996
>> Math::log(1000, 10).round(15)
=> 3.0
```

The C language specification [only *requires* 10 significant decimal places](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.2p11) for a `double`, so it is possible that a Ruby implementation would have `Float`s with fewer than 15 significant decimal places, but still it is much more common to see 15 significant decimal places here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [change of base formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base): If you can calculate a log with base `d` but you need log base `b` then `log_b(n) = log_d(n) / log_d(b)`. So:

```
> BigMath.log(1000, 50) / BigMath.log(10, 50)
=> 0.3e1
```

Now let's try with something that needs more precision:

```
> BigMath.log(999, 50) / BigMath.log(10, 50)
=> 0.2999565488225982308693534399304475375583359282738400141107276831709276456467950527020061473296516829369378125e1
```

Compare that with, say, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_10+999